# Как в WP_Query вывести по первому слову значения произвольного поля?

Tags: php, wordpress, wp-query

Всем привет. Столкнулась с проблемой. Вывожу данные по произвольному полю через данный код:

```
 $value_names = ['analyst',
'analyst oversmart',
'smartland verysmart',
'analyst verysmart undersmart',
] // Пример значений

        'meta_query' => array(
                array(
                    'key' => 'key_text',
                    'value' => $value_names,
                ),
            ),
```

key_text - произвольное поле.

$value_names - значение.

Как сделать чтобы выводились не все записи `$value_names`, а записи в которых совпадает первое слово `$value_names`.

т.е. результат должен быть таким: `analyst, analyst oversmart, analyst verysmart undersmart`

Comment: Это вообще возможно?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сама спросила, сама ответила. Ответ:

```
$value_names = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'key_text', true );
$perv_znach = strstr($value_names , ' ', true);
 'meta_query' => array(
                array(
                    'key' => 'key_text',
                    'value' => $perv_znach,
                    'compare' => 'LIKE',
                ),
            ),
```

Comment: Это нормальная практика на StackOverflow - делиться собственными знаниями в формате вопрос-ответ.

Comment: Одно замечание - LIKE отбирает при любом совпадении, не обязательно, чтобы совпадало первое слово. Т.е. `some analyst not very smart` тоже попадёт в выборку.

Comment: Для этого я использую строчку `$perv_znach = strstr($value_names , ' ', true);` и вместо `some analyst not very smart` будет просто `some`